# tf.keras.layers.Reshape() is significantly slowing down execution speed

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, training

I have the following toy example to illustrate the problem I am having. The encoder is a pretrained Xception model (its forward step takes negligible time). The strange thing is that I get a huge speed boost (more than twice as fast) when I simply use `tf.random.uniform([32, 100, 2048])` when compared to getting the output from the encoder. This makes no sense since the size and type of the tensors are identical and therefore tensorflow should not be retracing. I would also like to mention that I do run each of the blocks of code below in different cells on jupyter notebook and not as one single block. I am really not sure how to proceed, so any help would be immensely appreciated!

```
@tf.function
def get_image_features(imgs):
    return tf.keras.layers.Reshape((100, 2048))(encoder(imgs))

@tf.function
def step(img_features, hidden_state, input_words):

    preds, hidden_state, _ = generator([img_features, input_words, 
                                     hidden_state], training=False)
    return hidden_state, preds

imgs = tf.random.uniform([32, 299, 299, 3])
img_feats = get_image_features(imgs)
hidden_state = tf.random.uniform([32, 512])
input_words = tf.random.uniform([32, 1, 1], maxval=10, minval=0, dtype=tf.int32)

# timing part I am interested in 
s = time.time()  
hidden_state, preds = step(img_feats, hidden_state, input_words)
input_words = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log(preds), 1)
print(time.time() - s)
```